# iOS-Facebook connect with UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am a beginner in iOS programming. I am trying to build an Facebook app using iOS SDK for facebook. I have downloaded and integrated the facebook SDK with my sample app. I have also created my app id. I am also able to start my app by (after facebook object creation):

```
[_facebook authorize:@"123456" permissions:_permissions delegate:self];
```

Here user authorization takes place within the default iphone browser.

After successful user authorization, I am trying to pass a facebook url pointing to a particular person's facebook wall, within a UIWebView. Now the problem that I am facing is that UIWebView opens up the url in which Sign In/Login option is again there, which should not be the case as I have already done the facebook authorization part.

So my question is how to pass the active facebook session within UIWebView, so that the authenticated user can straight away open any facebook url within UIWebView.

Strangely, instead of UIWebView if I use the following code to connect to a facebook url , i am allowed to successfully connect as an authenticated user:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.facebook.com/xmarshall123"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

The above code off course opens the default browser, and that's probably why I am able to connect to the facebook url as an authenticated user.

Please help.